# SSLHandshakeException while connecting to SF from a standalone java client via a proxy

Tags: apex, integration, java, error, ssl

I am trying to connect to a SF hosted APEX web service.
previously i managed to do so when i was accessing the service without a proxy mediating the communication.
On port the same standalone java client to client network which has proxy setup, i persistently face the SSLHandshakeException exception.

here is the code that i am using to access the service...

```
public class PSVM {

static final String USERNAME = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
static final String PASSWORD = xxxxxxxxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy;
static EnterpriseConnection connection;

public static void main(String[] args) {
  ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
  config.setUsername(USERNAME);
  config.setPassword(PASSWORD);
  config.setPrettyPrintXml(true);
  config.setTraceMessage(true);
  config.setProxy("proxyXYXYXYXYXYX.com.sg",8080);
  Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl");
  Security.setProperty("ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl");
  System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
  System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowLegacyHelloMessages", "true");
  System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl,handshake,record");

  try {
   System.out.println("Auth EndPoint: " + config.getAuthEndpoint());
   connection = Connector.newConnection(config);
   System.out.println("Auth EndPoint: " + config.getAuthEndpoint());
   System.out.println("Service EndPoint: "
     + config.getServiceEndpoint());
   System.out.println("Username: " + config.getUsername());
   System.out.println("SessionId: " + config.getSessionId());

   SessionHeader_element sh = new SessionHeader_element();
   sh.setSessionId(config.getSessionId());
   System.out.println(">>"+config.getServiceEndpoint());

   String temp = config.getServiceEndpoint();

   temp = temp.substring(0,temp.indexOf("com", 0)+3) + "/services/Soap/class/ApexWebServiceAttempt";
   config.setServiceEndpoint(temp);


   SoapConnection sc = new SoapConnection(config);
   sc.setSessionHeader(config.getSessionId());
   System.out.println(sc.welcomeTheWorld());


  } catch (ConnectionException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
}


}
```

**By using the javx.net.debug=ssl i get the below trace followed by the exception stack trace-->**

> Auth EndPoint: null WSC: Creating a new connection to
>   https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/30.0/0DFN00000008Oju Proxy
>   = HTTP @ proxyXYXYXYXYXY.com.sg/XXX.XX.XX.XX:8080 username null setting up default SSLSocketFactory class
>   com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl is loaded Installed Providers = 
>   IBMJSSEProvider2 Build-Level: -20120224   IBMJSSE2    IBMJCE
>     IBMJGSSProvider     IBMCertPath     IBMSASL     IBMXMLCRYPTO    IBMXMLEnc
>     IBMSPNEGO   SUN keyStore is: C:\Program
>   Files\IBM\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\security\cacerts keyStore type is: jks
>   keyStore provider is:  init keystore init keymanager of type IbmX509
>   trustStore is: C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\jdk\jre\lib\security\cacerts
>   trustStore type is: jks trustStore provider is:  init truststore
>   adding as trusted cert:   Subject: CN=Certum Trusted Network CA,
>   OU=Certum Certification Authority, O=Unizeto Technologies S.A., C=PL
>   Issuer:  CN=Certum Trusted Network CA, OU=Certum Certification
>   Authority, O=Unizeto Technologies S.A., C=PL   Algorithm: RSA; Serial
>   number: 0x444c0   Valid from Wed Oct 22 20:07:37 SGT 2008 until Mon
>   Dec 31 20:07:37 SGT 2029
>
> adding as trusted cert:   Subject: CN=KEYNECTIS ROOT CA, OU=ROOT,
>   O=KEYNECTIS, C=FR   Issuer:  CN=KEYNECTIS ROOT CA, OU=ROOT,
>   O=KEYNECTIS, C=FR   Algorithm: RSA; Serial number:
>   0x1121bc276c5547af584eefd4ced629b2a285   Valid from Tue May 26
>   08:00:00 SGT 2009 until Tue May 26 08:00:00 SGT 2020
>
> ----------------------------------------------------
>
> adding as trusted cert:   Subject: CN=AddTrust Qualified CA Root,
>   OU=AddTrust TTP Network, O=AddTrust AB, C=SE   Issuer:  CN=AddTrust
>   Qualified CA Root, OU=AddTrust TTP Network, O=AddTrust AB, C=SE
>   Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1   Valid from Tue May 30 18:44:50
>   SGT 2000 until Sat May 30 18:44:50 SGT 2020
>
> SSLContextImpl:  Using X509ExtendedKeyManager com.ibm.jsse2.uc
>   SSLContextImpl:  Using X509TrustManager com.ibm.jsse2.yc JsseJCE: 
>   Using SecureRandom  from provider IBMJCE version 1.7 trigger seeding
>   of SecureRandom done seeding SecureRandom instantiated an instance of
>   class com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl IBMJSSE2 will not enable CBC
>   protection JsseJCE:  Using cipher AES/CBC/NoPadding from provider TBD
>   via init  JsseJCE:  Using SecureRandom  from provider IBMJCE version
>   1.7 JsseJCE:  Using KeyAgreement ECDH from provider IBMJCE version 1.7 JsseJCE:  Using signature SHA1withECDSA from provider TBD via init 
>   JsseJCE:  Using signature NONEwithECDSA from provider TBD via init 
>   JsseJCE:  Using KeyFactory EC from provider IBMJCE version 1.7
>   JsseJCE:  Using KeyPairGenerator EC from provider TBD via init 
>   JsseJce:  EC is available IBMJSSE2 will allow RFC 5746 renegotiation
>   per com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiate set to none or default IBMJSSE2 will not
>   require renegotiation indicator during initial handshake per
>   com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiation.indicator set to OPTIONAL or default taken
>   IBMJSSE2 will not perform identity checking against the peer cert
>   check during renegotiation per
>   com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiation.peer.cert.check set to OFF or default
>
> Is initial handshake: true Ignoring unsupported cipher suite:
>   SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unsupported cipher
>   suite: SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unsupported
>   cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring unsupported
>   cipher suite: SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   %% No cached client session
>   *** ClientHello, TLSv1 RandomCookie:  GMT: 1387420364 bytes = { 40, 188, 202, 103, 37, 64, 117, 50, 154, 37, 59, 214, 33, 57, 54, 189, 86,
>   56, 107, 239, 214, 186, 48, 184, 228, 65, 16, 28 } Session ID:  {}
>   Cipher Suites: [TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV,
>   SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
>   SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
>   SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
>   SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
>   SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
>   SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
>   SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
>   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
>   Compression Methods:  { 0 } Extension elliptic_curves, curve names:
>   {secp256r1, secp192r1, secp224r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, secp160k1,
>   secp160r1, secp160r2, secp192k1, secp224k1, secp256k1} Extension
>   ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed] Extension server_name,
>   server_name: [host_name: test.salesforce.com]
>   *** main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149 main, received EOFException: error main, handling exception:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection
>   during handshake main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description =
>   handshake_failure main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2 main, called
>   closeSocket()
>
> com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to
>   https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/30.0/0DFN00000008Oju  at
>   com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:129)
>     at
>   com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection.login(EnterpriseConnection.java:1080)
>     at
>   com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection.(EnterpriseConnection.java:399)
>     at
>   com.sforce.soap.enterprise.Connector.newConnection(Connector.java:35)
>     at PSVM.main(PSVM.java:36) Caused by:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection
>   during handshake  at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:202)  at
>   com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:272)   at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:234)
>     at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.startHandshake(qc.java:8)   at
>   com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:111)    at
>   com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:18)  at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1099)
>     at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(b.java:11)
>     at
>   com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectRaw(JdkHttpTransport.java:115)
>     at
>   com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connect(JdkHttpTransport.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:107)
>     ... 4 more Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down
>   incorrectly   at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:152)    at
>   com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:369)   ... 14 more

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Thanks in Advance!!
Nitin

Comment: welcome to sfse nitinK, I've taken the liberty to format the code and error message in your question. That can be done by using the{} and " buttons in the editor. Makes the questions somewhat more readable.

Comment: Thanks Samuel... as you can gauge, I am new this portal... i'll keep that in mind the next time...

Comment: Hi Samuel,

It turns out that it was the proxy that was blocking my outgoing requests.
the box that i was working on was not added to the proxy whitelist to connect to SF.
Once that was done, Wella!!!.

Thanks a lot for the help...

Comment: Might make sense to make an answer out of that, or remove the question again.